# jQuery change img of user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

Hy everybody.

I have this code:

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aQZ7Q/)

```
<div class="fl edit_options div_img">
<img class="img" src="${admin.img}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Foto do Administrador" />
<div class="input_photo dropdowndiv"> <span>Alterar Foto</span>

    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file_photo" id="file_photo" value="Alterar Foto" />
</div>
<br />
<p>Administrador: ${admin.username}</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.dropdowndiv').hide();
        $('.div_img').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdowndiv').slideUp('fast');
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdowndiv').slideDown('fast');
        });
```

CSS:

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.fl {
    float: left;
}
.edit_options {
    margin: 50px;
}
.div_img {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.edit_admin img, .edit_admin p {
    text-align: center;
}
.input_photo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 54px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: rgba(170, 173, 168, 0.9);
    display: table;
}
.input_photo span {
    height: 54px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
}
.input_photo input {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 54px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you can see, is not working as it should, ie, show the div when mousing over the image.

I also believe that the way I did, it was too polluted. I believe there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result in this context, I would like your help.

I think little miss. And if someone has a plugin that makes jquery to upload the photo it shows me a screen to resize the image with a predefined size (the 200x200) and make the cut when accepted, would be very grateful.

Thank.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the events switched

- slideDown means show
- slideUp means hide.

You have them reversed

```
    $('.div_img').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdowndiv').slideDown('fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdowndiv').slideUp('fast');
    });
```

---

The animation does not happen because of `.input_photo { display: table; }` That is because jQuery can not animate tables out of the box. If you set the type of a block element, you will see it animated just fine.

Comment: no no, I want be opposite. To display the div over the photo only when I hover over the photo.

Comment: Which is what my code will do! You are doing the opposite. Your code hides the div on mouseenter and shows it on mouseleave. My code will show it on mouseenter and hide it on mouseleave! Try it!

Comment: wowww, really! sorry, but, where I'm wrong? The div appears and does not rise.

Comment: Because you set it as a table display. Updated my answer.

Comment: really, but, without this, the text is not centered.

Comment: My code is too messy? If you have a way to do better, and be able to teach me, I would be grateful. I did the way I did, but I do not know if it's the best.

Comment: Wrap the "table" with a div and animate that. http://jsfiddle.net/aQZ7Q/3/

Comment: dont centralize horizontali.

Comment: Set the table width to 100% `.input_photo {
    display: table; width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

## [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

`.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )`

When the cursor goes in, you want the text to slide down, so it appears. Calling `slideUp()` just made the browser try to hide the `div` which is *already* hidden.

---

## Solution

Try reversing your functions:

### JavaScript/JQuery

```
$('.dropdowndiv').hide();
$('.div_img').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.dropdowndiv').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.dropdowndiv').slideUp('fast');
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/aQZ7Q/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to show the upload option when the mouse goes over the photo area then the following should fix it.

```
$('.dropdowndiv').hide();
$('.div_img').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdowndiv').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $('.dropdowndiv').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: Works man, but, where I'm wrong? The div appears and does not rise.